# How to get confusion matrix y_true from custom_data_generator

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, semantic-segmentation

How to get from custom_data_generator?

I know through model.predict can get y_pred data , but I dont know how to get y_true .

I found some writes but they introduce Imagedatagenerator of keras

```
data_generator = CustomDataGenerator(image_folders, label_folders, **params)
model = unet()
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('test1.hdf5', monitor='loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
train_history=model.fit_generator(data_generator, steps_per_epoch=200,epochs=30,callbacks=[model_checkpoint])

y_true = []  
y_pred = []  
y_pred = model.predict(train_history)
y_pred_cm = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)

cal(y_true, y_pred_cm)
```

```
class CustomDataGenerator(Sequence):
    ...
    def get_data(self, batch):
        ...
            label_one_hot = to_categorical(scaled_label, num_classes=self.n_classes)

            X[i,] = image
            y[i,] = label_one_hot

        return X, y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the provided code snippet, it seems that y_true is being generated within the CustomDataGenerator class. The get_data method of the CustomDataGenerator class generates the X and y data batches, where y represents the ground truth labels.

To access y_true data, you can modify the CustomDataGenerator class to store the labels in a separate list.

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical

class CustomDataGenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, image_folders, label_folders, **params):
        # Initialize the generator

    def get_data(self, batch):
        # Generate X and y data for a batch

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # Get a batch of data

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        # Execute operations at the end of each epoch

    def generate_y_true(self):
        y_true = []
        for i in range(len(self.image_folders)):
            # Generate the ground truth labels for each image folder
            label_folder = self.label_folders[i]
            # Generate the labels based on your desired logic
            # Here, 'to_categorical' is used assuming the labels are categorical
            labels = to_categorical(generate_labels(label_folder), num_classes=self.n_classes)
            y_true.append(labels)
        return np.concatenate(y_true, axis=0)
```

In this modified CustomDataGenerator class, the generate_y_true method generates the ground truth labels for all the image folders. It assumes the existence of a function generate_labels that generates labels based on the provided label_folder. You can replace generate_labels with your own logic to generate the ground truth labels.

To obtain y_true, you can call the generate_y_true method after training the model:

```
y_true = data_generator.generate_y_true()
```